# bot command undefined arg

Tags: python, discord.py

Can anyone advise why the bellow fails?

```
def add_api(arg, api_number):
    if arg in db:
        print("Name already exists")
    else:
        db[arg] = api_number

def get_api(arg):
    number = db.get(arg)
    return number


def search_api(search):
    match_keys = db.prefix(search)
    return {k: db[k] for k in match_keys}


@bot.command()
async def item(ctx, *, arg,):
    ''' KEEP '''

    number = itemapi.get_api(arg)
    if number:
        print(f"{arg}'s number is {number}")
    else:
        matches = itemapi.search_api(arg)
        if matches:
            for k in matches:
                print(f"{k}'s number is {matches[k]}")
        else:
            print(f"It looks like {arg} does not exist")
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 54, in <module>
    number = itemapi.get_api(arg)
NameError: name 'arg' is not defined
```

Comment: `itemapi.get_api(arg)` - The variable `arg` does not exist in this scope. You need to _define_ it

Comment: @h0r53 wouldn't the arg be the users input when submitting command?

Comment: To clarify when a user enters !glasses i want it to return the number for glasses or the number for glasses and sunglasses (if both exist in get_api)

Comment: The original code was malformatted. I aimed to correct it, but I may have messed up your spacing. Please review and let me know first that it is formatted correctly.

Comment: I think the main issue is in your definition here `async def item(ctx, *, arg,):`. It should likely be this: `async def item(ctx, arg):`. If you do want a variable number of arguments, the correct way to do so is this: `async def item(ctx, *arg):`

Comment: @h0r53 So i'm thinking it should only be one argument (as long as that argument can be more then one word, which I'm unsure of)

original code is here https://mystb.in/SuppliedAncientWarnings.ruby

Comment: It is because u when ran command u didn't specified agr. So this error came.